# Convert Element to Option

Tags: javascript, dom, xmldom

Is there a way to convert an Element Object to an HTMLOption object?
I have one code that looks like this:

```
var request = getXMLHttpRequest();

            request.onreadystatechange = 
                function (){
                    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                        var regions = request.responseXML.firstChild;
                        document.getElementById('selectedRegiao').appendChild(regions.childNodes[1]);
                    }
                }

            request.open("get", "getRegions.php?country=" + country,true);
            request.send();
```

I know that this code does not work and is not specified but I think It is enough to give the idea about what I am trying to accomplish. The element with the id selectedRegiao is a `<select>` tag.`<br>`
regions is XML. It looks like this:

```
<option name="val1">val1</option>
<option name="val2">val2</option>
```

I wanted to convert it in a quick and easy way to an Option tag. I know how to do it in the long way but. Is there a direct and quick way to do it?

Comment: The answer may be no but the solution is plausible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the option elements from XML using

```
var optsFromXml = regions.getElementsByTagName('option');
```

That would give you an options collection to handle in html. Like appending to some `<select>` element:

```
someSelect.appendChild (
          new Option( optsFromXml[0].getAttribute('name') )
); //=> appends option with value/text from name attribute
```

Comment: @Kooilnc By the way you've written you seem to have understood what I want but regions.getElementsByTagName('option')[0] is an Element Object not an Option Object and someSelect.appendChild(optsFromXml[0]) is now allowed.

Comment: You're right, you can't append just like that. Corrected: see edits, and http://jsfiddle.net/AttTa/

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
var newOpt = new Option(document.getElementById('selectedRegiao').innerHTML, document.getElementById('selectedRegiao').value);

selectObject.options[index] = newOpt;
```

Comment: You really did not understand what I wrote... Need help?